# JSON with array and dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, parsing, dictionary

I need to parse a JSON which contains two dictionaries inside one array. The two dictionaries have the same key. How can I parse them correctly.
Here's the JSON:

```
{
"your_ip": "131.49.768.11",
"list": [
    {
        "state": {
            "speaker": "false",
            "the_new_ip": "192.168.1.1"
        },
        "address": "cc: d2"
    },
    {
        "state": {
            "mic": "false",
            "the_new_ip": "192.168.1.5"
        },
        "address": "e0: b2"
    }
],
"error_code": 0
 }
```

This is how I parse it:

```
 NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.receivedData       options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray *array = [json valueForKey:@"list"];

for(NSDictionary *dict in array) {

  NSDictionary *newDict = [dict valueForKey:@"state"];

   NSLog(@"dict %@", newDict);

    NSString *IP = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [newDict objectForKey:@"the_new_ip"]];

      NSString *theUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", IP];

    NSLog(@"ip %@", theUrl);
```

From NSLog I'm getting two response, with two different IP (one from the first dict and another one from the second one). Is this the correct way to do so ? If yes, how can I save the NSString of the two IP that I get ? NSUserdefaults saves only one of them.
Thank you.

Comment: your json is not passing the valdation.. pls provide full json

Comment: {
    "your_ip": "131.49.768.11",
    "list": [
        {
            "state": {
                "speaker": "false",
                "the_new_ip": "192.168.1.1"
            },
            "address": "cc: d2"
        },
        {
            "state": {
                "mic": "false",
                "the_new_ip": "192.168.1.5"
            },
            "address": "e0: b2"
        }
    ],
    "error_code": 0
}   @Selvin

Comment: This is just wasted motion: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",`.  (And doubly wasted, since you do it twice on the same string.)

Comment: yes, right. but what about my question? @HotLicks

Comment: You get two values, you do with them whatever's appropriate for your situation.  We have no idea what you're planning to do with those values.

Comment: No, I only get two difference NSLog. 2014-10-12 15:37:46.659 App-In[1998:535316] ip port 21.535.94.37 and another one with different ip @HotLicks

Comment: That's what I said -- you get two values.  If your goal was simply to NSLog them then you're done.  What do you want to do with the values???

Comment: I need to save them into a NSUserdefaults. But If I save the NSString (the one which give me two NSLog) it only gives me one IP, not the two IP that I get from the NSLog. @HotLicks

Comment: Sorry, you're not making sense.  You have two values.  You can either save them separately or (if it makes sense to you) concatenate them into a single string.  Understand that we have on idea what your above data "means", nor do we have any idea what you eventually plan to do with the data.  We can't read minds.